# Using phone's unique device identification number instead of account

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have an idea for my mobile app where it does not use traditional account like account username and password. Instead it will use device's unique identification number as an anonymous account.

I have some questions.

I have never developed a mobile device before so is it possible to get unique identification number on all platforms especially iOS and Android?

Can I assume that all devices in the world have unique identification number and nobody could change theirs to be similar to other number?

Will there be any legal or technical ramifications for using identification number instead of old-fashioned way of using account with username and password?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea as the same user should be able to use your mobile app on multiple devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it possible to get unique identification number on all platforms
>   especially iOS and Android?

Yes, it's fairly possible to uniquely identify device installation. You could refer to [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) as a starting point

> Can I assume that all devices in the world have unique identification
>   number and nobody could change theirs to be similar to other number?

No. There's no such thing as super-unique-id-which-is-used-in-all-devices-in-the-world. Although each mobile phone has it's unique ID (IMEI, MEID, or ESN), it's not guaranteed to be unique in real world, since it can be changed. But there are other devices, which do not have telephony hardware (for example, tablets), thus they don't have IMEI. A different number should be used to identify such devices.

> Will there be any legal or technical ramifications for using
>   identification number instead of old-fashioned way of using account
>   with username and password?

No, I don't think so. Device number is not some private property, hidden from everyone

In general, identifying a user by their device ID is a bad approach and has no practical implementation. Why do you think it's still not used everywhere? Just a couple of point which ruin everything:

1. user changes their device (buys a new one)
2. user sells their device (new owner)
3. user has multiple devices

and, of cource,

4. users device stolen
5. unique ID emulated (or duplicated due to some collision)

Answer (score 1):

My 2-cents' in regard to modern mobile devices:

1. Theoretically yes, such as WI-FI and BT MAC
2. Personally I don't think using unique HW ID is anything bad especially mobile devices nowadays is becoming to be an unique ID itself: Apple Pay, NFC, smart card, face recognition, fingerprint, etc. In a sense, your mobile phone number is itself an unique ID, just like your email address, aren't they?  If mobile devices remain non-unique what good does it do except to be a "desk phone on the run"? We might as well keep using beeper and install millions of coin-inserted payphones.